# Google Maps Api City Wrong Results, something wrong?

Tags: google-maps

I'm getting wrong results, is this a bug on google maps API ? I want you feedback to check your results. Type the zipcode of "4430-201" and Let me know if you get "Lagos"(wrong) or "Vila Nova de Gaia" (correct)

This affects only me or other users? **This causes wrongly taxes applied during shipping calculations if reversing zipcode to city etc**...

```js
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#search").click(function(event){
        $.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",{address:$("#zipcode").val()},function(outs){
    
          $("#result").html(outs.results[0].address_components[1].long_name);});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="zipcode" type="text"/>
<button type="button" id="search">Go</button>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

This is my result:

[image: My Result2]

**UPDATE:**
All Google GeoLocation at least is messed up. When I search on google maps "Vila Nova de Gaia" it will tell me on the map that Vila Nova de Gaia is now "Lagos" and summary title is wrong... Why?

Also this is not happening to every people the same, how can they show different results to different people!? Also on my house with the same IP, i have different behaviours.

Look:

[image]

Comment: All bugs could have consequences...

Comment: What was your result? @alberto

Comment: It does return Vila Nova de Gaia as the result. What is the bug that you are referring to?

Comment: The bug is google then. I get lagos using the same input. So google api is not giving reliable results. Cannot trust it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see I'm not Crazy! Google is Wrong And cannot be trusted any more right now... Plus,I dont live in Lagos! What else could be wrong! Can you imagine driving directions to a place you don't know, and be mistaked by google to go to the other end of portugal! Because thats where Lagos is!

[image]

Comment: It looks like it depends from where the ip is called, in this case calling this from portugal will give wrong results. So the city has 2 different and wrong names in one of the databases or something like that...

Comment: Not, its not the IP, my friends on the same network have different results